# Number of artifacts Blocked for download as part of XRAY watch in JFROG

Tags: artifactory, jfrog-xray

I am looking for an REST API/AQL that can be used to generate the number of artifacts blocked for download as part of the XRAY watch violations in JFROG

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per this publicly available [page](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Xray+REST+API), the REST API is not available at the moment which can reveal the artifacts that are not downloadable because of vulnerabilities.

When we download an artifact that is having a vulnerability, then Xray can indicate if the artifact is not downloadable because of vulnerabilities init.